# Where can I find the source of the preconfigured workflows?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, activiti

Alfresco Community v5.2 includes preconfigured workflows, such as:

- New Task - Assign a new task to yourself or a colleague
- Review And Approve (single reviewer) - Assign a review task to a single reviewer
- Review and Approve (one or more reviewers) - Assign a review task to multiple reviewers
- Review and Approve (group review) - Assign a review task to a group

...and more.

On the basis of these preconfigured workflows, I want to create my own. To see how they work, etc. So I have a question: Where can I find it?..

I would like to see:

1. **BPMN 2.0 process definitions**
2. Workflow content models
3. Configurations for the Alfresco Share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the workflow BPMN in the JAR file `alfresco-repository-5.*.jar` deployed in WEB-INF/lib. You have to look in the subfolder: `alfresco/worklow`.

For the content models, look at the file `alfresco/model/bpmModel.xml` in the same JAR.

For the Share config, look at `WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/share-workflow-form-config.xml` in Share.